# SELECT from MySQL Database with PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

Right now my login page is working fine. If both username and password are correct it returns a value of 1 and direct you to a page called studentloggedin.php
In my database table i have a field called 'occupation' where there are two values: 'student' or 'lecturer'.

My problem is to create an if statement where if the user is a student it direct me to studentloggedin.php else it directs you to lecturerloggedin.php

I already tried to do a query but it isn't working.. please help :) MY code is here:

```
<?php 
session_start();
//*********Server Information to establish a connection ******

$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'kurtfarrugia';
$password    =    '1234';
$database    =    'kurt_farrugia';

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Error in Server information');
mysql_select_db($database,$link) or die('Can not Select Databasse');

//***************End Connection Establishment***************************************
//*******Form Information********

$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //User Name sent from Form
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); // Password sent from Form

$rememberMe = strip_tags($_POST['rememberMe']);
setcookie("username", $_POST['username']);

//*********retrieving data from Database**********

$query = "select * from tbladmin where admin_usr_name='$userName' and          
admin_pwd='$password'";

$res = mysql_query($query);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

//**********it ensures that the script does not continue unless the username varaible     is not null and not empty
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));
} else {
    //die('Hey turd, go back and fill in your username!');
    header( "Location: login_fail2.php" ); die;
}

/*if ($rememberMe) {
    setcookie("loggedIn", "yes", time()+3600);

    header ("Location: studentloggedin.php" ); die;
             }
else {
     echo "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
}


if ($_COOKIE['loggedIn'] == "yes") {
    header ("Location: studentloggedin.php" );
    die();
}
*/
// HERE is the query 

//$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT occupation FROM tbladmin WHERE admin_usr_name    ='$username'" == 'student');
//$row == mysqli_fetch_array($result)

//**********if $userName and $password will match database, The above function will    return 1 row
if($rows==1)
//{
{
 //***if the userName and password matches then register a session and redrect user to    the studentloggedin.php

 //$_SESSION['userName'];
 //$_SESSION['password'];

    header("location:studentloggedin.php");
}
//}

else
{
    header( "Location: login_fail2.php" ); die;
}

?>
```

Comment: please stop using mysql_* functions .. switch to PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: try changing `header("location:studentloggedin.php");` to `header("Location: studentloggedin.php");` - got a feeling HTTP headers are fussy

Answer (score 0):

Just try below:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT occupation FROM tbladmin WHERE admin_usr_name    ='$username'");


$rows = $result2->num_rows;

if($rows==1) 
  header("location:studentloggedin.php");
else
 header("location:lecturerloggedin.php");
```

Comment: There's no need for the second query, you can get that info from the first query, and you just need to add the if in there.

Comment: You have a logic flaw in your code, you need to check the occupation not the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your query:

```
//$result2 = $mysqli_query($con,"SELECT occupation FROM tbladmin WHERE admin_usr_name    ='$username'" == 'student');
//$row == mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

you can't use = to something == to something else.

here is the entire code as i think should work

```
<?php 
session_start();
//*********Server Information to establish a connection ******

$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'kurtfarrugia';
$dbpassword    =    '1234';
$database    =    'kurt_farrugia';

//Open connection   
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $dbpassword, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//***************End Connection Establishment***************************************
//*******Form Information********

$userName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); //User Name sent from Form
$userPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); // Password sent from Form

// $rememberMe = strip_tags($_POST['rememberMe']);
setcookie("username", $_POST['username']);

//*********retrieving data from Database**********


$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `tbladmin` WHERE `admin_usr_name` = '".$userName."' and `admin_pwd` = '".$userPassword."'");
if($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
{
    if($row['occupation'] == 'student')
    {
        // redirect logged student
    }
     else if($row['occupation'] == 'lecturer') 
    {
        // redirect logged lecturer 
    }
} 
else
{
     //username doesn't exist redirect to fail page
}

//**********it ensures that the script does not continue unless the username varaible    
is not null and not empty
if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));
} else {
    //die('Hey turd, go back and fill in your username!');
        header( "Location: login_fail2.php" ); die;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the part that you need

```
if (!isset($_POST['username']) || $_POST['username'] != '') {
    // redirect back to the form
}
if (!isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] != '') {
    // redirect back to the form
}

$userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbladmin WHERE admin_usr_name = '$userName' AND          
      admin_pwd = '$password'";

$res = mysqli_query($query);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($res);

if ($numrows == 1) {
    // here you can add the code with remember me
    $dataRow = myqli_fetch_row($res);
    $username = $dataRow['admin_usr_name'];

    if ($dataRow['ocupation'] == 'student') {
        // redirect to student php file
        exit;
    } else {
        // redirect to lecturer
        exit;
    }
} else {
   // redirect to login incorrect
   exit;
}
```